# Consulta sobre ionic y bd sin internet

Tags: android, angularjs, base-de-datos, ionic

Mi consulta es la siguiente ,quiero hacer una app en ionic que permita enviar reportes de x tipo a un servidor rest ,bien el servidor trabaja con una bd mongo , aqui una vez que tengo los reportes puedo hacer cualquier cosa , pero que pasa si el dispositivo android donde esta instalado la app no tiene internet ,estuve pensando que debería usar una bd en el mismo android(soy relativamente nuevo en android, no se si esto se pueda , de ser así que bd seria mejor postgress,o cual recomiendan),siguiendo ,luego de ello tendría que haber como una variable que revise el estado de internet en todo momento ,esto como podría programarse en una funcion , como ionic usa angular estuve pensando que en una función de inicialización tal vez... , luego guardar esta información offline en la bd , y cuando hay internet enviar estos reportes que no pudieron enviarse por no haber interne(esto lo manejaría con crons?), estas son todas mis dudas con respecto a este tema , agradecería la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre que podrías utilizar SQLite, para guardar tus datos y así accederlos de manera offline.
Existe el plugin de Cordova que funciona con Ionic.
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/

Dependiendo la versión de Ionic que utilices, podrías utilizar Ionic-native para los plugins.

Por otra parte, como vos mismo mencionas. Podrías realizar una función con el servicio $timeout de angular, para revisar el estado de conexión del teléfono, cada un determinado periodo de tiempo.

Ten en cuenta que para poder saber el estado de la conexion wifi por ejemplo, también vas a tener que utilizar otro plugin de cordova que te permite ver el estado de las distintas conexiones:
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/